# Archs Setting to Build Target of Pod Runner

Tags: flutter, dart, ios-simulator

I have read multiple posts on this but when I run the flutter project.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
main.dart:1
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `FlutterMacOS` from `Flutter/ephemeral`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/macos`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/macos`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_database` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/macos`
    firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.6.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/macos`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_auth":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_auth (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/macos`)
    Specs satisfying the `firebase_auth (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/macos`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
```

This error arises. I have tried deleting `pod.lock` and then reinstalling pods. I have tried updating cocoa pods. Deleting `.symlinks`, `pods/` folder and then clean building from scratch but nothing worked.